# Retrieve data from Firebase with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I made firebase realtime database that look like this:

[image: firebase database structure]

And now I want to simply get that data in my javascript code (I am using React-Redux-Saga technology)

My simplyfied code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const result = yield firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`laivuzaidimas/`)
  .once('value');
console.log('result is retrieved: ', result);
```

What I get in console after retrieving data:

[image: Retrieved data]

What should I do now? How to get the array that is in database? As I understand, I got only a snapshot and now I need to somehow extract what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
firebase.database().ref().once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
   console.log('result is retrieved: ', snapshot);
   snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
    let key   = childSnap.key;
    let photo = childSnap.val().photo;
    let name  = childSnap.val().name;
 });
});
```

Retrieve the data using `once()` and since `once()` returns a `Promise` then use the method `then()` to wait until the data is fully retrieved. When the data is retrieved use the `forEach` to loop inside the data and retrieve the values.

Comment: I can get snapshot to print in console in your method, but I am not getting childSnap printed or name printed if i do: 
          console.log('childSnap: ', childSnap);
          const { name} = childSnap;
          console.log('name', name);

Comment: I get your point, but I meant that it is not printing wrong value, but not showing such console statement as "childsnap: " undefined (or etc.) at all

Comment: Though it prints out snapshot as I added in a picture in my question

Comment: but did you add `val()`? if you do `let name  = childSnap.val().name;` console.log(name)` under it, then it should print the name..

Comment: I mean, when i do 
        snapshot.forEach(childSnap => {
          console.log('foreach loop is looping!');     I dont get anything in console

Comment: So I cant wish to have name printed if loop is not working

Comment: did you copy the code exactly as it is in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I think my problem is that snapshot does not have any childSnap. Maybe you know how I could check how much of childSnap it has?